# Get the Contents of multiple files in directory

Tags: swift, macos, nstableview

I need to get the contents from multiple `plist` files and bring them into a single `dictionary` which is then displayed in a `tableView`

Using this code I can manually get each path and the contents of the file but I need to be able to do this for all plist files in the directory not just these predefined ones.

```
    func getFiles() {
    let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let path = documentDirectory.appending("/MainFolder/File1.plist")
    let path1 = documentDirectory.appending("/MainFolder/File2.plist")
    let path2 = documentDirectory.appending("/MainFolder/File3.plist")
    tableViewData = [NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as! [String : String], NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path1) as! [String : String], NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path2) as! [String : String]]
    print(tableViewData)
}
```

I the display `tableViewData` in my `tableView` which gives me each files contents on its own row.

I am guessing I probably need an array of file urls filtered by `.plist` and then some way to get the contents of each file into a `[String : String]` dictionary.

I am new to swift, any help or a better way to do this would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all don't use outdated and *objective-c-ish* `NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains` in Swift. Use the modern`FileManager` API.

Second of all don't use *objective-c-ish* `NSDictionary(contentsOf` to read property list data. Use `PropertyListSerialization`.

The function `throws` that means it hands over all possible errors to the caller. It filters the URLs in the directory by the `plist` extension and uses the `map` function to get the dictionary for each URL.

```
func getFiles() throws {
    let documentDirectory = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let subFolderURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MainFolder")
    let allFiles = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: subFolderURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
    let properListFiles = allFiles.filter{$0.pathExtension == "plist"}
    tableViewData = try properListFiles.compactMap { url -> [String:String]? in
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
        return try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as? [String:String]
    }
    print(tableViewData)
}
```

Be aware that in sandboxed apps the `Documents` folder is located in the application container.

Answer (score 0):

You can read all the plists and iterate over them adding their contents either to 1 array, or to an already kept dictionary.

```
do {

let directoryContents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentDirectory, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])


let allPlistFiles = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "plist" }
var aPlistArray = []
for aPlist in allPlistFiles {
aPlistArray.append(NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as! [String : String])
}

} catch {
    print(error)
}
```